# Sequence sum Discrepancy

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sum of first $N$ natural numbers is: $$\frac{N(N+1)}2$$
If I divide the sequence into two parts for some value $M$ where $1< M < N$, then the sum of first $M$ natural numbers will be: $$\frac{M(M+1)}2$$ and the sum of last $N-M$ numbers will be: $$\frac{(N-M)(N+M+1)}2$$ and the difference between the sum of two parted sequences will be: $$\frac{N^2 - 2M^2 -2M}2$$
However, this fails for $N=3$ and $M =1$.

Sum of the first sequence $=\frac{1 \cdot 2}2 = 1$.

Sum of the remaining sequence (last $N-M$ numbers) $=  \frac{(3-1) \cdot (3+1+1)}2 = 5$.

Difference $= 4$.

However, if we put the values in the formula, it equals $\frac{3^2 - 2 *1 *1 - 2 *1}2 = \frac{9-2-2}2 = 2.5\ne4$

Why is this discrepancy arising?

Answer (score 0):

You have made  a slight mistake in your calculation. The difference between the two sums is $\frac {N^{2}-2M^{2}-2M+N} 2$.